# classic asp like recordset object, how to design it in .net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable

With the help of you guys, I have created an object that is similiar to the recordset in classic asp.

```
public class RecordSet: List<Dictionary<string, object>>
{

}
```

So I can access the data like:

```
RecordSet rs = new RecordSet();

rs[rowID]["columnName"];
```

How can I get access like this also, i.e. ordinal referece:

```
rs[rowId][2];
```

**Please don't ask me why I just don't use a datatable, this is partly for fun and learning and testing hehe**

Comment: I planned a fuller reply, but haven't the time, sorry - but I really don't recommend the List<Dictionary<string,object>> approach. All that should be encapsulated - just exposing the bare minimum.

Answer (score 3):

Something that would work more like a RecordSet could look like this:

```
public class RecordSet {

   private Dictionary<string, int> _nameLookup;
   private List<List<object>> _rows;
   private int _currentRow;

   ...

   public object this[int index] {
      return _rows[_currentRow][index];
   }

   public object this[string name] {
      return this[_nameLookup[name]];
   }

   ...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you want to look at the IEnumerable interface, which you can implement to be able to 'foreach' loop through the class's rows.